# Trying to access Instagram API using jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, instagram

I'm trying to use the Instagram API and I'm making AJAX requests in a do-while loop until the next_url is null. All I want this code to do is to fetch all the followers by making continuous requests until it's done. What is wrong in this code?

When I remove the do-while loop it doesn't gives me an error, but as soon as a I use the AJAX request within a loop, it never stops. Clearly the `$next_url` string is not changing to the newly fetched `next_url` - why? What is wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#fetch_followers').click(function(e) {
            var $next_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by?access_token={access-token}&count=100';
            var $access_token = '{access-token}';
            var $is_busy = false;
            var $count = 0;
            do {
                while($is_busy) {}
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: $next_url,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp : "callback",
                    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
                    success: function(data) {
                        $is_busy = true;
                        $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
                            $("#log").val($("#log").val() + item.id + '\n');
                        });
                        $("#log").val($("#log").val() + data.pagination.next_url + '\n');
                        $next_url = data.pagination.next_url;
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $is_busy = true;
                        //alert("Check you internet Connection");
                        $("#log").val($("#log").val() + 'Error\n');
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        ++$count;
                        $is_busy = false;
                    }
                });
            } while($next_url !== '' || $count <= 50);
        });
    });
```

After I failed in my logic, I added the `$count` variable that can break the do-while loop, because the do-while loop was running infinitely. After adding it, it still runs infinitely, and I have no idea why.

Comment: So you've placed you're entire ajax function inside a loop, and it crashes your browser every time, now what do we do ???????????????????????

Comment: Just tell me how to break the loop when it's done with fetching all the followers. Comment something helpful this time.

Comment: This approach won't really work for asynchonous ajax calls, because the loop keeps going even before the ajax call returns. One approach you can try is recursion, triggering each new ajax call in the success callback. That's going to be expensive though, so I would say simply rework your approach altogether, and see if you can reduce the number of ajax calls necessary and do more work server-side.

Comment: can you give a sample code as example? @nbrooks

Comment: actually, the whole point of this code was to take off load from the server, so doing something on the server side is not an option. @nbrooks

Comment: YMMV, but several AJAX requests chained together can present more of a load on the server than a single request - even if there is a bit of extra processing to do server-side with the latter. Initiating connections is expensive. On average, how many chained requests will you make per set, out of interest?

Comment: @halfer, depends on the number of people that are following the user, an average Instagram user has about 500-20K followers, Instragram-API responds with maximum 100followers per request.

Comment: OK, your frontend speed _may_ be improved by grouping these into blocks of X (where X > 100). Experimentation on slow browser connections will help here (they may benefit by being grouped say in blocks of 200). But, if you insert 20K items into the DOM it'll be slow for anyone `:)` - maybe that needs to be paged in some way?

Comment: About what you were saying, broaden your point.. :) @halfer

Comment: I made several points (which is why I asked you to clarify). One is that if you download 20,000 items of data (e.g. social network followers) then fitting them all on screen is a problem, as is the speed of doing so. That could be 250Kb+ of data (quite large for AJAX ops) and a _lot_ of jQuery DOM manipulation. Also, if you limit your AJAX calls between your server and the client to 100 items, then to retrieve 20K followers, that'll be 20 separate requests to the server in quick succession. Might it not be better to show 100 followers initially, then "the next 100" upon a click?

Comment: That sounds just about right, just to clarify, the cap of max 100followers is set by Instagram-API, and I can't help but to deal with it somehow. If only I could ask for all 20,000 followers in a single request, it would be awesome. Now coming to the many Ajax requests point, yes it would be better to show the the next 100 followers upon a click, but just think about it, this is not optimal for every scenario, the user mostly wants the app to do all the work. And I should bring this up, some users have about a million+ followers.

Comment: @halfer, I wanted you to broaden the point where you used the term "paging", i'm curious about knowing more.

Comment: Paging: it's just the process of splitting long result sets into pages - see the bottom of any search engine where there are more than 10 or so results. Otherwise, you're going to be rendering thousands (or 1million+) followers on-screen, which is clearly infeasible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have the function call itself in the ajax success callback with the new url as a parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fetch_followers').click(function() {
        var $access_token = '{access-token}';
        pollInstagram('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by?access_token={access-token}&count=100');
    });
});

function pollInstagram(next_url, count) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: next_url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data.data, function(i, item) {
                $("#log").val($("#log").val() + item.id + '\n');
            });
            $("#log").val($("#log").val() + data.pagination.next_url + '\n');

            // If the next url is not null or blank:
            if( data.pagination.next_url && count <=50 ) {
                pollInstagram(data.pagination.next_url, ++count);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert("Check you internet Connection");
            $("#log").val($("#log").val() + 'Error\n');
        }
    });
}​
```