# Instagram get profile data

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

Is it possible to use jQuery or javascript to get the amount of followers a user has on instagram and then display that number inside a div element? I've found several PHP answers but I can't use PHP. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram supports RESTfull webservices. The solution you found for PHP can also be used in jquery. You just need to make `jsonp` calls to the server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Trying to access Instagram API using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712106/trying-to-access-instagram-api-using-jquery)

Use something similar. Use the resulting JSON data to print the followers number into a div.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#fetch_followers').click(function(e) {
            var $url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token={access-token}&count=100';
            var $access_token = '{access-token}';
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: $url,
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp : "callback",
                    success: function(data) {
                       $('#followers').append(data.counts.followed_by);
                    }
                });
        });
    });
```

The code is rough, untested, but something along those lines will work.